# Mongo Atlas freetier limit MongoCommandException

Tags: mongodb-atlas

i'm using mongo atlas free tier.
i thought mongo free tier limit size is 512MB. but the data keeps inserting.
please someone explain how it happend.

sometimes i recieve below response. than i can't insert data.
but my free tier get over 1GB data. so it mean that without that response, i can insert more data.
it makes me confusing the limit of size.
what is real limit? and how can i insert more than 512MB?

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8000 (AtlasError): 'you are over your space quota, using 513 MB of 512 MB' on server XXX. The full response is {
    "ok": 0,
    "errmsg": "you are over your space quota, using 513 MB of 512 MB",
    "code": 8000,
    "codeName": "AtlasError"
}
```

Comment: This is most likely related to how they enforce their limits. Most likely the limits are a marketing concept, implemented on top of databases which are the same.  Then from time to time they might run a job to check the usage of each database, and lock/warn those that have gone over plan.

Comment: thank you to explain that. i didn't think like that before. depends on their implementing, inserting data is locked! thank you to let me understand this issue!